# How many green onions are in a bunch?

Tags: measurements

I have a lot of green onions but my recipe calls for a small bunch. Roughly how many green onions would I find in any of the following?

- Small bunch
- Normal bunch
- Large bunch

Comment: a small bunch. pick up of table were sold. just above the onion head. with thumb. bring finger around them were you can hold them to bottom of thumb. medium bunch. pick up with thumb bring finger to thumb joint. large bunch pick up with thumb bring finger to tip of thumb. That is with out mashing them to put on scale at market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can at least show you what ALDI in Germany considers a bunch:

[image: bunch on scale]

[image: in hand]

It weighs about 200g and if I wrap my hand around it, my finger touches the middle joint of my thumb, which according to JBergen's comment, makes it a medium bunch.

And in this bunch are....
[image: unwrapped]
Seven onions!

But the exact number is probably not really important. Cooking can be a pretty exact science occasionally, but most of the time, a bit more or less won't make or break a recipe. So use common sense and the 7 onions / 200g per medium bunch as a guideline. If your onions are especially pungent, you might want to cut back, if they are mild or you want a bit of a punch, be more generous.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that it is not exact, a guideline number is exactly what needed. I’d guess one could consider a bunch “small” if either the green onions themselves are smaller or you take maybe two out of the “normal” bunch. And most times when the recipe calls for a “small” bunch I’d just use a whole bunch anyway—otherwise I would have to figure out what to do with the unused green onions.